# How to make Cypress visit work headless on remote server?

Tags: cypress

I have a url I wish to `visit` with Cypress. 
When I run on localhost, headless or with Cypress GUI - it works.
When I run on my remote server, the GUI works but the headless does not.

This is the test:

```
describe('bootstrap', () => {
  it('should redirect to login', () => {
    cy.visit('localhost:8000').then((response) => {
      expect(response.location.pathname).to.eq('/login');
    })
  });
});
```

The Screenshot that is created doesn't give new information, and when I added `cy.wait(20000)` I think it didn't wait.

What am I missing, how can I make this test run on the remote server?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after we changed to: (thanks [Erik Zaadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110124/erik)!)

```
describe('bootstrap', () => {
  it('should redirect to login', () => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/login')       +         
  });
});
```